# How to play tactically in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I had been playing Battlefield games since the beginning, but I came to CS:GO and I noticed that there is **no fast-paced gameplay style**, indeed I had to play **tactically**.

I used to play fast because I had players with **Support and Medic** kits along me, making me not to worry abut being killed and getting run out of ammo.

How can I **change** my gameplay style to get adapted in CS:GO?

***Note:*** I especially love game modes like **Arms Race**. (it is much more like Battlefield)

Comment: It really is too broad and opinion based to answer. There is no one recipe on how to do it. The WarOwl has ALOT of clips (that are old but very valid) that teach how to play, one of your better bets is to go trough these.

Comment: If you want to **change** your style, you'd have to first explain what is your current style of play before anybody will know how to adapt it for CS style playing.

Comment: Also if you know the Rush B joke, you'd know that fast pace offence is definitely possible. Not every engagement is about two jokers throwing 4 flashes 2 smokes and 2 decoys.

Comment: Way too broad.. You should narrow down your question to an actual issue. Teaching the whole game play with a single answer is impossible. Also since you can respawn in arms race getting killed is no real problem. Just don't get stabbed or you lose levels.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who put this question as **too broad**. I know I was just asking too much from this question. I hope that I never repeat the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By playing **tactically**, I assume you mean **the playstyle used in competitive mode.** The thing about that is, CS:GO has always been made to be played with a competitive mindset, and while there are other gamemodes, there is quite a difference between Competitive mode and the others.

Gamemodes likes Deathmatch or Arm Races are made for you to quickly kill and die, because you can buy the weapons you want as often as you like: this results in the game being way more fast paced, but get this: it greatly reduces the experience factor. These gamemodes are made for you to learn how to shoot guns, and to know the maps. What I am getting at is, the tactical part of CS:GO really kicks in in Competitive mode, where the stakes are high, you cannot afford to die just to get a kill and you are working with a team towards a goal.
My point is, there is no use playing strategically in modes other than Competitive because it's just a huge mess, and you shouldn't rush in the ennemy team in Competitive because that would also be missing the point.

**That being said**, here are the advices I can give you to learn what we call the "brain" side of gameplay in CS:GO.
Firstly, I would advise using a headset if you aren't already, because "sounding" is very important. Sounding is what takes place when you try to hear ennemy footsteps to deduce their locations. CS:GO's sounds engineering allows that.

Secondly, I would also say you should start by playing the same maps over and over to get to know them. In my CS:GO days, I only played Inferno, for example. Each map offers a great range of hiding, shooting, and embushing position you should learn. Playing the same map over and over will also allow you to predict what distance the ennemy at the beginning of the round because you will know how far he could go around the map in a given time period.
"Playing tactically" also involves learning where to plant the bomb, where to hide to protect it, and making quick choices, such as deciding to defuse and risk it or killing the ennemies but letting the bomb blow because you were too slow.
If you so wish, you could go watch professional players play because you can learn a lot of things you might not suspect from the game by their playstyles.

**Changing your gameplaystyle** means being aware of your surroundings, gaining quicker reflexes, managing ammo, life and grenades by being cautious before going out of your hiding position, in summary.

Comment: I think you meant "stakes", not "steaks" in your second paragraph. What a yummy "misteak" :D

Comment: Quite good, I liked how you got my problem correctly and explained about it very nicely; voted for the accepted answer.

Comment: Aye, english is not my first language. I only heard of stakes in spoken documents, so I kind of overlooked looking for the exact way of writing it. Thanks for letting me know, I'll fix it.